# Flutter onBackgroundMessage android myimage notification not working

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

Flutter firebase background notification I pushed the image notification but it's showing only text but if app open it's working fine but app terminated or minimize it's showing only default notification I tried everything but it doesn't work I referred this also https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging no use.

[check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNzj1.png)

background notification not showing that image?

**Application.kt**

```
package YOUR PACKAGE

import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin
import io.flutter.view.FlutterMain
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService
import com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin

class Application : FlutterApplication(), PluginRegistrantCallback {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this);
        FlutterMain.startInitialization(this)
    }

    override fun registerWith(registry: PluginRegistry?) {
        if (!registry!!.hasPlugin("io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging")) {
            FirebaseMessagingPlugin.registerWith(registry!!.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin"));
        }
        if (!registry!!.hasPlugin("com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications")) {
            FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.registerWith(registry!!.registrarFor("com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin"));
        }
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
 package YOUR PACKAGE

 import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity

 class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
 }
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="YOUR PACKAGE"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <application
        android:name=".Application"
        android:label="APP_NAME"
        android:icon="@drawable/home_logo"
        tools:replace="android:label">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <!-- Add below to ensure we get the payload when tapping on a notification -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
             <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
                android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id"/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**main.dart**

```
_firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print('on message $message');
        showNotification(message);
      },
      onBackgroundMessage: Platform.isIOS
          ? null
          : myBackgroundMessageHandler,
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print('on resume $message');
        showNotification(message);
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print('on launch $message');
        showNotification(message);
      },
    );
```

**myBackgroundMessageHandler method in same main.dart**

```
 static Future<dynamic> myBackgroundMessageHandler(Map<String, dynamic> message) {
    final notification = message['notification'];
    final data = message['data'];
    print(notification);        
  }
```

**Firebase send notification json Rest API**

```
    #header:
        Content-Type:application/json
        Authorization:key=YOUR FIREBASE SERVER KEY
    #body -> raw
        {
          "notification":{
          "title":"Plan Expired",
          "body":"Your plan has expired please upgrade your plan today"
           },
           "data": {
                "image":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/zZ72Ujn8Rfw/maxresdefault.jpg"
           },
          "to":"NOTIFICATION TOKEN"
        }
```

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: @ManikandanM You could edit the question, if you want to make it clear, cheers

Answer (score 0):

To show images you may need to use image tag **inside notification** in your **Firebase send notification json Rest API**. The below code worked for me.

```
     {          
         "notification":{
          "title":"Plan Expired",
          "body":"Your plan has expired please upgrade your plan today",
          "image":"https://imgsv.imaging.nikon.com/lineup/dslr/df/img/sample/img_01.jpg"
           }
          "to":"NOTIFICATION_TOKEN"
        }
```